# Android Smartphones which are compatible with Multicast

Tags: android, multicast

I'm looking for a list of Android Smartphones where I can do multicast.

I know multicast can be different on the same smartphone but under different android version.

So I'm looking for a specific list of brand and model where multicast can be used.`

If anyone can give me a list or a model which he test I will be happy anyway.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Android have consistency in supporting muticast.

IGMP was missing on different HTC, Samsung, and Motorola devices of all android version from 2.1 up to 3.2.

Please refer below link.

http://www.programmingmobile.com/2012/01/multicast-and-android-big-headache.html

Thanks.